# Как сравнить значение атрибута со строкой?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`this.querySelector('.down_img')` выдаёт такой HTML код тега:

```
<img src="fr_2.png" class="down_img">
```

Но `this.querySelector('.down_img').attr('src')` говорит:

> this.querySelector(...).attr *is not a function*

Мне надо взять значение из `src` и сравнить его со строкой `fr_2.png`.

Comment: 0. Надо различать javascript и java. 1. Надо отличать html-код от dom-элемента. 2. Надо отличать jquery от нативного js. 3. Естественно это не функция, потому что у dom-элементов такого свойства нет. 4. Даже для jquery жлательно не путать prop и attr. 5. Впрочем с prop не очень-то и сработает.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```js
    window.onload = function () { // При загрузке документа
        let val = document.querySelector('.down_img'); // Получаем элемент с классом.
        let src = val.src; // Получаем его src
        // Надо уточнить, что src всегда указывается относительно пути. Например http://localhost:63343/help/fr_2.png
        // Соответственно нам необходимо получить именно название файла
        let name = src.split('/').pop(); // Разбиваем по / и получаем последнее значение
        if(name == 'fr_2.png'){ // Проверяем название файла. Если совпадает с нужным значением то...
            console.log('Найден такой элемент'); // Например выводим в консоль (Тут можете добавить свои действия).
        }
    }
```

```html
<img src="fr_2.png" class="down_img">
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает.
Можете пожалуйста пояснить что это за ключевое слово let?
В моём курсе этого не было.

Comment: @Nikto Да не за что. Это объявление переменной, вместо `var`. Советую к прочтению. https://medium.com/nuances-of-programming/%D0%B2-%D1%87%D1%91%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-var-let-%D0%B8-const-%D0%B2-javascript-3084bfe9f7a3

Comment: Извините, но у меня остался последний вопрос.
Если вместо document использовать this, то появляются ошибки, мне нужно использовать this т.к моя задача: у меня много кнопок для свёртывания div'ов,
также, на сайте есть форма для добавления этих кнопок и div'ов принадлежащих этим кнопкам, при нажатии на любую из них, тот div который её принадлежит должен свернуться в размерах.
Если использовать document это работает не так. 
Вот структура: <ul><div id=main><div id="header">Оставить<button>Свернуть footer</button></div><div id="footer">Свернуть</div></div></ul> В ul много main-div'ов

Comment: Курс которой я купил содержит мало полезного, но требования там большие.
Пожалуйста, помогите, а то возможно меня отчислят.

Comment: @Nikto. Предлагаю переместиться в чат. https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/106267/nikto-denis640kb?tab=general

Answer (score 1):

```js
const srce = $('img.down_img').attr('src'); // берешь
console.log(srce === 'fr_2.png'); // сравниваешь
```